# reheating leftover omelette on stove in pan without overdrying or making it too oily?

Tags: reheating, omelette

I am, probably, a beginner at cooking (can make a small variety of dishes well). Of late, I have been expanding my skill set and have been striving to reheat leftovers (no more than a day or two old) on stove.

For omelette leftovers, which I originally cook in butter, I add about half a tbsp butter for reheating. But it ends up oily in some places and dry in others.

Is there a particular amount of butter or other oil best for reheating omelettes? Should any liquids be added?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to reheat an omelette & arrive back at 'a fresh omlette'.
You serve it just before it's completely cooked, so it arrives at the table correctly finished. Five minutes later hopefully it's been eaten, before it's past its best.

Anything after that is going to be rubbery.
Reheated is going to be rubbery++, no matter what you do.

To be perfectly honest, if you really want to reheat one, put it in the microwave for 30s to 1m. It's never going to get any better than that… & it will add no oil.

Re-heatable 'omelette' might best be considered as ['Spanish tortilla'](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/spanish-tortilla), which is never meant to be light & fluffy in the first place & microwaves rather well. If you keep half for tomorrow, or buy one in a supermarket, ready-cooked, then the microwave is actually the best way to get it back to temperature. Re-heating in a pan is a) slow & b) will over-cook the outside before the inside is to temperature.

Comment: oh good to know. Out of curiosity, is this an issue specific to egg dishes--they are too delicate to reheat well?

Comment: Eggs are very delicate. Many egg dishes are served 'early' so by the time they get to the table residual heat has finished the cooking. Eggs - fried sunny-side-up, scrambled & omelette are all examples of this approach. Tortilla is an opposing method. (All are delicious;)

Comment: This answer is spot on.  I mostly eat stuff that I can batch cook and reheat (stews/curries etc.); even stir-fries reheat better than omelettes. In that context, omelettes are a nice change from dinners consisting mainly of stuff in sauce with rice/pasta, and are a convenient quick-cooking standby.  It's worth having a pan the right size to cook the amount you'll serve in one go.  If you must end up reheating, I'd chop it and add it to cooked drained rice, veg etc. and fry in sesame oil, adding soy sauce, for a sort of inauthentic egg fried rice.